# Textarea within a list is not aligned

Tags: html, css

Looking at [this simple code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdEowM) why the textarea is pushed 10/15 pixel down?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I fix this via css? I wish to have the textarea inline with the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` is a `block` element

So either you use `display:inline-block` ( or inline, depending on what you want ) on the `div`

```css
div {
display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Either you use `float:left` . But i suggest you don't do that. Using float left will get the element out of the normal flow

> Elements after a floating element will flow around it. To avoid this, use the clear property or the clearfix hack.

Comment: "*A block-level element always starts on a new line*" If you put text inside of `div` instead of `textarea` above statement will be false.

Answer (score 1):

Using `float:lett`
Try this, it works fine  :

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style = 'float:left' >
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="text-div">
          <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.text-div{
  float: left;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

it's because you have used list-style. remove it through css

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
```